# System.JSONException in Salesforce Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I got error in test in this condition.

```
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&  (parser.getText() == 'periodName' )) {          
        break;
    }
}
```

error is

> System.JSONException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker
>   for ARRAY (from [Source: java.io.StringReader@569b9883; line: 1,
>   column: 118]) at input location [1,485]

can anybody help me.

**EDIT :**

The JSON is :

```
{"status":"REQUEST_SUCCEEDED","responseTime":42,"message":[],"Results":{ "series": [{"seriesID":"LAUCN040010000000006","data":[{"year":"2014","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"20410","footnotes":[{"code":"P","text":"Preliminary."}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"20750","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"20863","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M05","periodName":"May","value":"20321","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M04","periodName":"April","value":"19919","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M03","periodName":"March","value":"20309","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M02","periodName":"February","value":"20055","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M01","periodName":"January","value":"20499","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M13","periodName":"Annual","value":"21130","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M12","periodName":"December","value":"20358","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M11","periodName":"November","value":"20190","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M10","periodName":"October","value":"20614","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M09","periodName":"September","value":"20963","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"21457","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"21611","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"21684","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M05","periodName":"May","value":"21408","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M04","periodName":"April","value":"21177","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M03","periodName":"March","value":"21059","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M02","periodName":"February","value":"21324","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M01","periodName":"January","value":"21715","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M13","periodName":"Annual","value":"22061","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M12","periodName":"December","value":"21695","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M11","periodName":"November","value":"21459","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M10","periodName":"October","value":"22063","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M09","periodName":"September","value":"22312","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"22640","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"22924","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"22479","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M05","periodName":"May","value":"21935","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M04","periodName":"April","value":"21624","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M03","periodName":"March","value":"21778","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M02","periodName":"February","value":"21813","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M01","periodName":"January","value":"22014","footnotes":[{}]}]}] }}
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON parsed ?

Comment: Thanks for reply 
{"status":"REQUEST_SUCCEEDED","responseTime":42,"message":[],"Results":{ "series": [{"seriesID":"LAUCN040010000000006","data":[{"year":"2014","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"20410","footnotes":[{"code":"P","text":"Preliminary."}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"20750","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"20863","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M05","periodName":"May","value":"20321","footnotes":[{}]} my json is something like this.

Comment: Something like this or exactly like this ? It seems that your parser find a wrong character during parsing.

Comment: This is exactly same but something like that means i paste just part of json because full json is very long i can't post here... and i think no error in json because my all functionality is working fine. i get all data in salesforce from class but only problem in test class.

Comment: The error message refers to character 1485 but you have only provided about 500 characters of JSON. Post the full JSON as an edit to the original question.

Comment: Copy and paste you test-case JSON through e.g. http://json.parser.online.fr/ to make sure there isn't a problem in it. Clearly at the moment there is.

Comment: I have paste my full JSON can you please help me. Also i have copy and paste my JSON at json.parser.online.fr but i didn't get any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at the data you've provided I can create this, which runs fine

```
String jsonText = '{"status":"REQUEST_SUCCEEDED","responseTime":42,"message":[],"Results":{ "series": [{"seriesID":"LAUCN040010000000006","data":[{"year":"2014","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"20410","footnotes":[{"code":"P","text":"Preliminary."}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"20750","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"20863","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M05","periodName":"May","value":"20321","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M04","periodName":"April","value":"19919","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M03","periodName":"March","value":"20309","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M02","periodName":"February","value":"20055","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M01","periodName":"January","value":"20499","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M13","periodName":"Annual","value":"21130","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M12","periodName":"December","value":"20358","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M11","periodName":"November","value":"20190","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M10","periodName":"October","value":"20614","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M09","periodName":"September","value":"20963","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"21457","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"21611","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"21684","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M05","periodName":"May","value":"21408","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M04","periodName":"April","value":"21177","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M03","periodName":"March","value":"21059","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M02","periodName":"February","value":"21324","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M01","periodName":"January","value":"21715","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M13","periodName":"Annual","value":"22061","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M12","periodName":"December","value":"21695","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M11","periodName":"November","value":"21459","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M10","periodName":"October","value":"22063","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M09","periodName":"September","value":"22312","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"22640","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"22924","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"22479","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M05","periodName":"May","value":"21935","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M04","periodName":"April","value":"21624","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M03","periodName":"March","value":"21778","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M02","periodName":"February","value":"21813","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M01","periodName":"January","value":"22014","footnotes":[{}]}]}] }}';
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonText);
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&  (parser.getText() == 'periodName' )) {          
        break;
    }
}
```

How are you getting the data into your parser in the test class? Is it a String assignment? The error refers to 1485 so try checking that you haven't introduced a new line or something like that mid-way through the String.

You can also add a debug of the String before invoking the parser.
e.g. System.debug(jsonText) to see if it has been corrupted in a way you don't expect.

Comment: yes thank for help. it working fine in my class but error in test class. but its give me now 63% coverage without any error. with this statement in my main class.  if (!Test.isRunningTest()){ }

Answer (score 1):

A good step in troubleshooting parsing issues is to try validating your data. There are online resources available to parse JSON data like http://jsonlint.com/ and http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Comment: I paste my JSON at http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ its display valid JSON. Also its give error in test class only not in my class, all functionality working fine.